# Converted an Angular app to android using cordova. The apk starts on the emulator but only a blank white screen appears on the actual device

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am converting an angular app using cordova to an android app. The converted apk file comes up on the emulator. But when I install it on the actual device and run it shows up just a white blank screen. Waited for quite a long time but never came up. I am new to this cordova and android and any help is much appreciated.

Even the sampleHelloWorl app does not come up on the device.

Steps followed.

1) ng new HelloWorld

2) cd HelloWorld

3) make in index.html

4) ng build --prod

5) in the same folder create a cordova project by executing cordova create mobile-app com.example.hello OurFirstApp 5) cd mobile-app and copy all the angular output files to cordova www directory i.e del -r www ; cp -r../dist/HelloWorld/* www

6) cordova platform add android

7) cordova build android

8) cordova emulate android --> application comes up on the emulator

to run this on the device I did below

9) cordova build --release android

10) cd platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release

11) keytool -genkey -v -keystore helloappworld.keystore -alias helloappworldmobileapps -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

12) jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore helloappworld.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk helloappworldmobileapps

13) zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release-signed.apk

14) I then uploaded app-release-signed.apk to my google drive and tried to install and then open. It gives a white blank screen

angular cli version is 8.3.19 . Cordova version is 9.0.0 and the github repo is github.com/ruksan/AngularHelloWorld.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did the following change in tsconfig.json and it worked
"target": "es5"

thanks a lot @Nidhin Joseph for helping out on this

Answer (score 0):

[As per this article](https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/02/cordova-vs-zonejs-or-why-is-angulars-document-event-listener-not-in-a-zone.html), the reason for the might be because Cordova and Zone.js is monkey-patching window.addEventListener and document.addEventListener.Cordova, however, is assigning a new function to those methods kicking out Zone.js and hence change detection does not work anymore. One way to beat this is to restore the previous prototype inheritance as below.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  window.addEventListener = function () {
    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  window.removeEventListener = function () {
    EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  document.addEventListener = function () {
    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  document.removeEventListener = function () {
    EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

The second method is to reorder the way `cordova.js` is included.

Comment: I am not clear where I should add the above code. In the converted cordova project, there is this index.js file which has var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);} . I replaced the body of this function with the given gode. Now it's says connecting to device. Then I just added the code into the body keeping the existing code. Now it says 'device is Ready'

Comment: Still the application screen does not come up

Comment: the above script needs to go after cordova.js script is included.

Comment: Tried this. But no luck. Is there anyone who has done this who can share the code of the hello world amgular app converted to android and working on the physical device. Much appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You add `<base href=".">` into the index.html's head tag.
The screen blank issue will be fixed.

Comment: Heads up!
Your answer is not a complete solution to this question.
When this occurs, you must enter it as a comment.